# How do I stop checkdoc from flagging header/footer in org-src-edit buffers?

Tags: flycheck, advice

When editing Emacs Lisp source blocks in `org-mode` via `org-src-edit`, if `flycheck` is enabled (which I'd like to keep that way) `checkdoc` rather annoyingly remarks that I'm missing headers and footers and commentaries and whatnot. In `checkdoc` itself, it seems that if the buffer has a name, it's going to get checked for commentary:

```
    (or (and buffer-file-name ;; only check comments in a file
             (checkdoc-comments)))
```

So `checkdoc-comments` does a couple of useful things, and I'd be sad to see it go entirely, but it's gotta go. I thought some advice could help:

```
(define-advice checkdoc-comments (:around (original))
  (unless (org-src-edit-buffer-p)
    (funcall original)))
```

(A better version might filter out the offending errors instead of not checking anything, but I wanted to keep it simple.)

This works great when calling checkdoc manually via `M-x checkdoc`. Comments are excluded. But somehow, flycheck seems to ignore my advice. I don't understand why, as [flycheck's source code](https://github.com/flycheck/flycheck/blob/master/maint/flycheck-checkdoc.el#L34) doesn't seem to have a special version of `checkdoc`. Am I not understanding how advice is supposed to work?

Is there another way to do what I want to do?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: OK, I thought the question about how and why advice applies or why (in this case) it doesn't may warrant the elisp tag…